# Detect space and add a comma

Tags: c#

I have text file with employes email like this below

abc@ewr.com
xyc@df.co.nz
rte@pope.com
ssddsf@fdf.com

I want change to like this

abc@ewr.com, xyc@df.co.nz, rte@pope.com, ssddsf@fdf.com

How can i do using C# code?

Answer (score 4):

```
string yourString = oldString.Replace(' ', ',');
```

Most likely it is not a space but a new line, so it would be

```
string yourString = oldString.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
```

Answer (score 3):

Could do this;

```
    string linesFromFile = string.Empty;

    // Read into string from file
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename.txt"))
    {
        linesFromFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
        linesFromFile = linesFromFile.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",");
        Console.WriteLine(linesFromFile);
    }

    // Write back from string to file
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("newFilename.txt"))
    {
        foreach(string s in linesFromFile.Split(','))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use some of the methods in the "File" class.              File.WriteAllText(filePath, contents); or File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines);

Answer (score 1):

this would replace CR\LF and spaces with ','

```
string newContent = string.Join(",", 
                                File.ReadAllLines("sourceFile.txt")
                                ).Replace(' ', ',')

File.WriteAllText("newFile.txt", newContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd operate on the file directly to avoid the overhead of reading a potentially huge employee database into a string:

```
private static void MungeFile(string filename)
{
    FileStream fsOut = File.Create(filename+"_out");
    FileStream fsIn = File.OpenRead(filename);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fsIn);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fsOut);
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string inputLine = sr.ReadLine();
        string terminator = (sr.EndOfStream ? "" : ",");
        sw.Write(inputLine + terminator);
    }
    sw.Flush();
    fsOut.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's documentation covers this one pretty well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228599.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Read in the text file as a string, then do something like this to replace the newlines with a comma (replace Environment.NewLine with ' ' if you are looking to replace spaces):

```
String newFile = oldFile.Replace(Environment.NewLine,',');
```

Comment: How to read file and get 'newFile' string..I am extreme newbie to csharp